# Cross validation score for PCA

Tags: python, cross-validation, pca

I've recently seen an example (Python with scikit learn), where `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` was passed to `cross_val_score` as estimator with some data, like this

```
cross_val_score(PCA(n_components=10), X)
```

But how is it possible to measure any score if PCA doesn't produce any output, since it's not a learning method? Moreover, there was no `y` passed to the cross validation function, though the result was an array with several cross validation scores.

So the question is what exactly was computed there, inside `cross_val_score`?

P.S. I hope the question is not a Python specific, I just don't understand what mathematically can be a score in such a case?

Comment: May be these might help you: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43613443/11643735
2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41458834/11643735

Comment: Thanks, but these posts are about different things. I don't know what happens when I pass PCA to this function. For example, if we pass some regressor or classifier to `cross_val_score`, it runs `fit - predict` pipeline on folds and measures some accuracy, then returns accuracy values as an array. How this can work in case if there is no `predict` method (like in PCA)?